# AJAX Send JSON string to another domain

Tags: php, json, ajax, cross-domain

I understand that AJAX cannot work between two different domains. I need to send JSON data from one webpage to another domain who has a PHP page which will record that JSON data in a DB.

What I tried was to use AJAX to communicate with a local PHP file then have that PHP file POST to the destination domains PHP file.

My AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './remote.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        sentdata: data
    },
    success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("responseMsg").innerHTML = response;
    }
});
```

My Local PHP file remote.php:

```
$url = "https://example.com/destination.php";
$data = json_encode(($_POST['sentdata']));
$build = array('http' =>
   array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'content' => $data
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($build);
$return = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if($return) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
```

In destination.php on the domain I am trying to reach I have:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $data;
```

When it runs I see it echo "failure". The file_get_contents($url, false, $context); is not getting anything back.

Is there any reason this strategy for performing AJAX across to another domain would not work? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I also verified allow_url_fopen was set to on in php.ini

Comment: Is the `= =` just a typo? `$url = = "https://example.com/destination.php";`

Comment: And you're not actually making an AJAX *call* to another domain. You're calling `./remote.php`, presumably on the same domain, which is in turn accessing an external server via other methods, eg. `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Yes = = was an typo, I corrected it. Marcus, my understanding is that AJAX won't allow you to make the call directly to the external server, so this was my attempt to work around that. I understand It's not technically an AJAX call to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP cURL for sending that json data to another domain. Use AJAX to communicate with a local PHP file, where under that file is your cURL function to save and return response.

Here is the [PHP cURL doc](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php)  to get you started.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you! However Is there a reason my method mentioned above would not work instead?

Comment: maybe destination.php doesnt have the proper permissions

Answer (score 0):

It turns out everything I posted does work. There was problems in my external servers PHP file later on that were causing it to fail. After further troubleshooting it turns out this was not the problem.

As others have mentioned cURL would be a great solution for doing this also. However this works perfectly fine and does not require cURL.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use CURL get something from the url $url = = "https://example.com/destination.php"

Comment: As the other answer mentioned cURL seems like a good option, but right now I'm curious why this method I displayed would not work?